# Vetores em Python

Tags: python, array, python-3.x

Muito bem, venho da linuagem C,e estou tendo dificuldades em criar vetores no python. No C se eu escrevesse vet = [5]; eu criaria um vetor chamado vet com 5 indices. Queria saber fazer isso no python mas sou iniciante e não estou conseguindo. O ponto é, como determino a quantidade de indices que meu vetor irá ter?

Answer (score 9):

A resposta mais curta é: não define. Python é uma linguagem de programação de alto nível e tipagem dinâmica, você não precisa limitar o tamanho do seu vetor.

Aliás, o tipo em Python que mais se assemelha ao vetor do C é a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list). Para você definir uma nova `list`, basta fazer:

```
>>> meuVetor = []
```

Pode confirmar o tipo da variável fazendo:

```
>>> print(type(meuVetor))
<class 'list'>
```

Neste ponto é interessante lembrar que **tudo** em Python é objeto, por isso, mesmo que o tipo `list` seja nativo, ele é uma classe. Você pode verificar todos os métodos do vetor utilizando a função `dir`:

```
>>> print(dir(meuVetor))
[..., 'append', 'clear', 'copy', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']
```

Você pode inserir novos valores no vetor pelo método `append`:

```
>>> meuVetor.append(1)
>>> print(meuVetor)
[1]
>>> meuVetor.append(2)
>>> print(meuVetor)
[1, 2]
```

Teoricamente você pode fazer isso indefinidamente. O tamanho do vetor variará conforme o seu uso. Cresce e diminui por demanda.

Para acessar os elementos, é bem semelhante ao C:

```
>>> print(meuVetor[0])
1
>>> print(meuVetor[1])
2
```

Você pode inicializar o vetor com um número pré-definido de elementos:

```
>>> meuVetor = [0]*5
>>> print(meuVetor)
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Mas isso costuma ser desnecessário em aplicações mais básicas.

Para percorrer todos os elementos do vetor, basta utilizar o `for`:

```
>>> for(valor in meuVetor):
...     print(valor)
0
0
0
0
0
```

Isso funcionará independente do tamanho do vetor.

Se você precisar em algum momento verificar qual é o tamanho do seu vetor, você pode utilizar a função `len`:

```
>>> print(len(meuVetor))
5
>>> print(len([0] * 10))
10
```

> Para referências futuras, enquanto ler a documentação, tenha em mente que o tipo `list` é mutável.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado pela ajuda Anderson

Answer (score 2):

O python trabalha com [listas](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```
lista = [1, 2, 3]
```

As quais são variantes de **tamanho** e de **tipo**, independentemente. Ao contrário do que acontece com o *Array* de outras algumas linguagens.

Caso queira criar uma lista com um número predefinido de elementos, além da atribuição, podes fazer:

```
lista = [None]*n
```

Sendo n o número de elementos. [`None`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#None) é o objeto vazio.

No python2, também podes usar o [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range), que cria uma sequência numérica em forma de lista. **No entanto, no python3, este mesmo [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) é apenas um objeto iterável** geralmente percorrido por um `for`, não uma lista.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Samir

Answer (score -2):

I usually do this

```
vetor=list(range(5))
for i in range(0,6):
   vetor[i] = 1
```

you can creat a vector of five positions

Comment: Bem Vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português a versão Lusofônica do Stack Overflow. Essa página é exclusiva aos usuários falantes de Língua Portuguesa. Aqui toda a comunicação deve ser feita em português. Caso queira utilizar o inglês como língua sugiro que visite a página do [Stack Overflow em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com)